# Example of $\aleph_1$-categorical linear order

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, linear-orders

Is it possible to have an $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentence $\phi$ in a vocabulary that includes $<$ that satisfies the following?

1. $<$ is a linear order on a definable subset;
2. $\phi$ is $\aleph_1$-categorical;
3. in the unique model of $\phi$ of size $\aleph_1$, $<$ is also of size $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Perhaps we can get to "no" by omitting types.  The right tools for this might be in John Baldwin's Categoricity (from the AMS or online), or @DaveMarker's primer on infinitary logic at http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/inf.pdf.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://www.jstor.org/stable/2274053 ?

Comment: I would imagine that quite a bit is known about this (but I haven't been able to make much of the Grossberg-Shelah paper). Do you know if requiring the domain of < to be the entire model makes a difference? Two minor observations : (1) The long line would appear to be an example, if the question were about $L_{\omega_1,\omega}(Q)$ (2) If there is a model such that for some countable subset of the domain of $<$ uncountably many gaps were filled, and $2^{\aleph_{0}} < 2^{\aleph_{1}}$, then there would be $2^{\aleph_{1}}$ many such linear orders. This is similar to Theorem 5.8 of .......

Comment: ...... my paper with Baldwin (http://www.users.miamioh.edu/larsonpb/galois_types_august17_15.pdf). So unless absoluteness of $\aleph_{1}$-categority for sentences of $L_{\omega_{1}, \omega}$ fails, you'd need an example where there is no such countable set. This may not help, of course.

Comment: @TimZ: Thank you for the paper. Indeed, it has interesting results, but I can not see how they help with the question at hand. Their conclusion is that certain $T$'s have the maximum number of models, but their assumption is that for every $\mu<\mu^*(\lambda,\kappa)$, there is a model $M_\mu$ and some $\phi$ defines a well-order of type $\mu$ on a subset of $M_\mu$. We have nothing of this sort here. Our $<$ is just a linear order. I can not see how to pull the well-order required. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) In fact, even the smallest $\mu^*$ cardinal is quite large: $\mu^*(\aleph_0,\aleph_0)$ equals $\beth_{\omega_1}$. So, we need a well-ordering with for every $\mu<\beth_{\omega_1}$.

Comment: @PaulLarson: I would expect a negative answer to my question whether $<$ is on the entire model or not. I just looked the long line up. It  is $\omega_1\times [0,1)$. Why is this $L_{\omega_1,\omega}(Q)$-categorical? The theorem from you paper with Baldwin seems to point to the right direction. If there is a model with $<$ having many gaps, then the answer to the question is negative. So, assume that in all countable models of $\phi$, $<$ does not have many gaps. Does this imply that $<$ is scattered?  (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) There is an old theorem that if $<$ is countable and scattered, then there is an $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$ sentence $\psi$ such that $(M,<^M)\models \psi$ iff $M$ is countable and $<^M$ is isomorphic to $<$. Corollary: If $(M,<^M)$ is a countable model and $<^M$ is scattered, then $M$ is not equivalent to any uncountable model. So, $\phi$ must have non-scattered countable models. Does this imply that there are "many gaps"?

Comment: I retract what I said about the long line. There should be $2^{\aleph_{1}}$ many models which are $L_{\omega_{1}, \omega}(Q)$-equivalent to it. I think the discussion starting on page 11 of this paper is relevant: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00318v1.pdf

Comment: One more comment: By definition, if $<$ is not scattered, then it embeds $(\mathbb{Q},<)$; therefore it has many gaps. By the contrapositive, if in all countable models of $\phi$, $<$ does not have many gaps, then $<$ is scattered in all countable models of $\phi$. By the previous comment, $\phi$ does not have any uncountable models. This will provide a negative answer to the question (modulo the comment by Paul Larson).